# Integrating Facebook with Wordpress or Drupal

Tags: facebook, integration, blogs

I just want to get some opinions before I tackle this head on. So far, I've set up a wordpress site and managed to get all post made on this site, appear on facebook on notes. However, all the plugins that do the following functionality that I require, have either been discontinued, or stopped working due to facebook changing their layout.

This is what i need:

1. The site can be either Drupal or Wordpress (but I'm willing to sacrifice that if there is some other app that I don't know of that can do the points to follow)
2. All posts made on my site, must be able to appear on Facebook as NOTES (both Drupal, Wordpress and pretty much anything with RSS feed capability can do this)
3. Any comments made on my site, must go to Facebook and appear there too. (this is probably NOT going to be possible, unless people end up logging in with their facebook details, which is not what I want)
4. **Any comments made on Facebook MUST appear on my site**

Point 4 is more important than point 3. I can live without point 3, but I CANT live without point 4. There are quite a few wordpress plugins that claim that they can do this, but I assure you, they don't work! They worked on the principle of scanning the page for content, and due to layout changes, it won't find the right values anymore.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [Facebook for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/fb) and [Facebook Connect](http://vishalsood.com/projects/drupal/facebook). They seem promising.